# Google App script, when I search column height increases

Tags: google-apps-script

I have Google App Script. This was running fine for months. Suddenly, Now when I run it works fine, however when I search anything heights of column increases dramatically. 
Here is link to my script https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzXTbgh-xA-MueYmyGI8j8aTFLymsuTayiEveLGWUUgsiceuWxH/exec

Comment: Can you please share your code here? For us to be able to help you out, we would need code to see where things might be going wrong. Also, is your Spreadsheet by any chance an old version Google SpreadSheet?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have found the fix I needed to add .setOption('height','100%') to table chart. This resolved the issue.